# Process for obtaining a prepaid micro-SIM card in Brunei

Tags: cellphones, brunei

What do I need to to do to obtain a micro-SIM in Brunei?

Specifically:

Will I need to present my passport?

Is there anything I should know about the telecommunications companies, for example, owned by the government?

Places to purchase the SIM, specifically with good English speakers.

Is there a vendor at the airport who sells micro-SIMs?

Any other information that would be helpful to a one-time visitor who plans on using a smartphone for about a week?

Comment: Since recommendations are usually subjective, I'm removing that wording from your question. I'm leaving in the part about buying somewhere English is spoken, because that is objective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brunei has two mobile operators, <s>b-mobile</s> [Progresif](https://progresif.com//) and [DST](http://dst-brunei.com/).  Both are privatized former state companies.

You will need to present your passport to get a prepaid SIM.  Both companies have booths at the airport, and all mobile shops in BSB sell them as well.  English is generally spoken in Brunei, although you don't really need it: showing them your phone and asking for a "prepaid SIM card" (in English) will get the message across just fine, and they'll set it up for you on the spot.

You're generally looking at around B$30 for the SIM plus credit.  At time of writing, b-mobile offers a package that gets you 9 days of unlimited data for B$20.

Comment: How is it that you seem to know *absolutely everything about everywhere*? (-:

Comment: Working in the telecom industry in SE Asia for 7 years helps. Also, Google ;)

Comment: Final result: B$38 for a DST SIM at a FastLink mobile shop (SIM came with $B5 credit). Passport only needed to 'register' SIM. As an 'unregistered' SIM it will stop working after seven days. Sounds like it's unlimited data for the week.

Comment: B-Mobile is now defunct. Its assets have been taken over by [Progresif](https://progresif.com/). Progresif has a booth at the airport.